# My racket scheme command line is not working correctly in Windows Powershell, what am I doing wrong

Tags: windows, powershell, cmd, scheme, racket

I can't get anything except the racket repl working correctly in Powershell. As a very basic example:

```
PS C:\> racket -e '(display "hi\n")'
hin: undefined;
  cannot reference an identifier before its definition
    in module: top-level
    internal name: hin
PS C:\>
```

Alternatively, running similar in cmd.exe (it seems to be confused by single quotes):

```
C:\Windows\System32>racket -e "(display \"hi\n\")"
hi

C:\Windows\System32>
```

Running the same in Powershell:

```
PS C:\> racket -e "(display \"hi\n\")"
string::10: read-syntax: unknown escape sequence `\)` in string
```

Runs fine in bash.exe:

```
$ racket -e '(display "hi\n")'
hi
```

Anything I can do to make racket run better in powershell?

Comment: You might want to try the PowerShell parameter parsing escape - `--%`. `racket --% -e '(display "hi\n")'`

Comment: Hmm, that works with the cmd.exe example in powershell, although it now trips up differently with single quotes: 

PS C:\> racket --% -e '(display "hi\n")'
string::2: read-syntax: expected a `)` to close `(`
PS C:\> racket --% -e "(display \"hi\n\")"
hi

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you are writing in Racket *in powershell*, which means that you have to make your `-e` string parse properly *before* it gets sent to Racket. You're not running into this problem in bash because bash is clever enough to let you have double quote (`"`) literals inside of a single quote (`'`) string. You can easily escape to get just a double quote in powershell with \", making your command be:

```
$ racket -e '(display \"hi\n\")'
hi
```

Comment: That's it! Thank you :)